# How to render a file from Devise module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise gem in my rails application for authentication. In idm_authenticatable.rb I have a method as follows..

```
 module Devise
  module Strategies
   class IdmAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
     def create_employee
       if !employee.save
         render 'devise/sessions/new'
       end
     end
   end
  end
 end
```

But the above method is throwing

```
 undefined method `render' for #<Devise::Strategies::IdmAuthenticatable:0x00000001771068>
```

I think we can't render from inside a Module. Is there any alternate way to render error page inside devise module?

Comment: What makes you think `render` is defined in your class?

Comment: @Nathan I didn't get you.

Comment: Where is `render` defined?

Comment: render is not defined. I just used like what we do in controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call `render` arbitrarily like that. The `render` method is defined in `ActionController::Rendering` which gets mixed into the controller and view stack in Rails.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Rendering/render

You can try to include that module into your class, but I wouldn't recommend it as it sounds like you're not completely sure what you're doing.

```
class IdmAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
  include ActionController::Rendering
end
```

Comment: now i am getting undefined local variable or method `response_body

Comment: Like I said, I would not recommend it. It's part of a larger stack of mixed in modules in Rails and you're not going to get it to work the way you want unless you understand those modules very well. My answer is mostly that you can't do what you're trying to do. You should post a new question describing the problem you're trying to solve... as the current implementation approach you're using is not reasonable.